# Reference multidemensional array element in MYSQL query

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This works

```
"SELECT firstName, lastName FROM table1 WHERE firstName=$resultArrays[one]";
```

however this multidimensional array element reference does not

```
 "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM table1 WHERE firstName=$resultArrays[one][first]";
```

can anyone explain why?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because php doesn't recognize the 2nd set of braces as part of the variable, so it thinks you're trying to interpolate `$resultsArrays[one]`, which is followed by the literal string `[two]`.

Because `$resultArrays[one]` is an array, you will get the following error

> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

and the following output

> SELECT firstName, lastName FROM table1 WHERE firstName=Array[two]

To properly interpolate arrays use curly braces and don't forget to quote your keys.

```
print "SELECT firstName, lastName FROM table1 WHERE firstName={$resultArrays['one']['two']}";
```

**Sidenote**

You should use prepared statements instead of interpolating variables into sql strings (which leaves your code open to sql injection). See [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)